# ¿Estan dentro del alcance del sitio las preguntas que piden el significado/uso de una palabra?

Tags: discusión

La pregunta: "[What do Chingón and Chinga mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/what-do-chingon-and-chinga-mean)" genero algo de polémica. Hubo los siguientes comentarios:

> I see you're trying to know about the meanings of different rude words
>   last days. You should totally drop that and try jQuery. – Arkana Jan 4
>   at 11:12"
>
> La primera fuente de referencia para el significado de palabras es
>   rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/drae – lorddarkangel Jan 4 at 18:12
>
> @Arkana Parece que quiere entrar en los carteles mexicanos, good for the JQuery idea...so >StackOverflow – Emilio Gort Jan 4 at 19:26
>
> @Arkana I don't think what he was asking is that kind of advice. Rude
>   words are part of a language as any other words, and who can tell
>   another which kind of knowledge is good or bad for him? –  Flamma 2
>   days ago
>
> @lorddarkangel aunque es cierto que el diccionario es la principal
>   fuente de conocimiento, como podras darte cuenta con la respuesta de
>   "razpeitia" hay muchos otros usos que no estan documentados en el
>   diccionario. – Alfredo Osorio 2 hours ago
>
> @AlfredoOsorio No te falta razón, pero no está de más recordar una
>   fuente tan útil como el diccionario de la RAE. Puede aclarar futuras
>   dudas de manera rápida y precisa, sin tener que pasar por aquí. Así se
>   dejan las preguntas más complicadas para este sitio. – lorddarkangel
>   47 mins ago

Sin embargo la pregunta gano buena puntuación (4 votos) que incluye el mío.

Dos cosas sucedieron con esta pregunta:

- Pide el significado de una palabra.
- Es una mala palabra (grosería).

Mis pregunta son:

- ¿Están dentro del alcance del sitio las preguntas que piden el
  significado/uso de una palabra ?
- ¿Se admiten también maldiciones o frases groseras?

Comment: Buena pregunta, esto debe ser discutido.

Comment: Para los que no participan en StackOverflow aqui esta la referencia a [You should totally drop that and try jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por supuesto que debe estar permitida tal pregunta. Genera conocimiento y el significado no se puede encontrar en el diccionario. La RAE no recolecta de manera completa el significado de varias palabras usadas regionalmente y dicha pregunta requiere la ayuda de expertos de este sitio. El DRAE, a lo mucho, provee un par de significados para regionalismos; sin un ejemplo bien formulado es imposible, incluso para hablantes nativos, adivinar lo que significa en tu totalidad tal palabra.

También creo que hay que ser autocríticos. Desde mi perspectiva, mucha gente en el sitio que raya en la intolerancia. No sólo hablantes nativos, sino gente que ha aprendido español a un buen nivel, y que sin embargo no ha entendido que las reglas del mismo no pueden ser tan estrictas para prohibir ciertos regionalismos, suele calificar de *mal español* o de *idioteces* a expresiones que son correctas en cierta extensión geográfica.

**Discusión tangencial.** Un ejemplo concreto de lo que intento explicar en el último párrafo es [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/que-haciendo-and-que-estas-haciendo), que tiene marcada una respuesta que, a mi parecer, es incorrecta (primero, porque no aborda la pregunta, y luego porque no hay "**un** español correcto"). Tampoco se puede culpar a los que la respondieron, pues la pregunta, en sí, debería especificar a qué región se refiere.

Por esa razón, ejemplos de respuestas que no creo que lleven a nada bueno son:

> (...) in writing, in very informal contexts, such as Facebook or SMS messages. I believe it is indeed a shortened form of ¿Qué estás haciendo?
>   I don't suggest using, ever. Even in these informal contexts....
>   Unless ur goal iz 2 mock the ppl who talk that way, or 2 B ironic. U will B h8ed.

o bien, la respuesta marcada como correcta:

> Qué haciendo? could be some type of expression typical from South America, although I've never heard it before, it could be some derivative from "Spanglish". "¿Qué estás haciendo?" is the correct form in Spanish to ask "What are you doing?"

Al mismo tiempo, comentarios del tipo

> "South America" in this context, includes America (the United States), or to be more exact, the Spanish-speaking elements of it. It is a place where many "corruptions" can be found. (by Tom Au)

incluso más ofensivos que *off-topic*.

¿A dónde voy? A que basados en que el español es tan complejo y geográficamente extendido, no creo que respuestas que califiquen expresiones como "mal español" de una manera dogmática sean bienvenidas. No sólo no generan conocimiento, sino que generan mentira.

Comment: Lo que puede sonar a una idiotez en mi país de origen puede ser una expresión cotidiana en otro, el problema es adaptarse al lugar donde se está, como tú dices `el español es tan complejo y geográficamente extendido` que ha evolucionado en el tiempo en cada región específicamente y hay que respetar las particularidades de cada lugar. La verdad no es absoluta, esto no es matemática donde siempre 1+1=2

Answer (score 2):

Como @Flamma dice en su comentario las malas palabras son parte del idioma y tienen un uso distinto en diferentes lugares, por ejemplo lo que puede ser una mala palabra en Cali, en Barranquilla no lo es y tienen hasta significados distintos.

Pienso que el significado de palabras polémicas debería estar dentro del alcance del sitio, no así la mera traducción de estas.

Me recuerda que obtuve un voto negativo por usar la palabra `testículos` y eso que no es una mala palabra.